# Xamarin.Forms in new window in Xamarin.Mac project

Tags: cocoa, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to embed a XAML page created with Xamarin.Forms in my native Xamarin.Mac application. And open this window as modal. But problem is that opened window ignore size 680х425 and opened as very small square. Where is my problem?
Here is my code:

```
            this.window = new NSWindow(new CGRect(new CGPoint(100, 100), new CGSize(680, 425)), NSWindowStyle.Closable, NSBackingStore.Buffered, false);          

            PickInstallPath pickInstallPath = new();

            this.window.ContentViewController = pickInstallPath.CreateViewController();

            NSApplication.SharedApplication.RunModalForWindow(this.window);
```

P.S If I remove line where I'm setting ContentViewController window opening in normal size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process for consuming a Xamarin.Forms ContentPage-derived page in a native project is as follows:

Add the Xamarin.Forms NuGet package to the native project.

Add the ContentPage-derived page, and any dependencies, to the native project.

Call the Forms.Init method.

Construct an instance of the ContentPage-derived page and convert it to the appropriate native type using one of the following extension methods:

CreateViewController for iOS, CreateSupportFragment for Android, or CreateFrameworkElement for UWP.
Navigate to the native type representation of the ContentPage-derived page using the native navigation API.

You can refer to this document to get more information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-forms

**Edit:**
You may want to call SetFrame **AFTER** you set the ContentViewController as the frame of the view controller's content will override the window's set frame,
or you can set the frame of the ViewController's content and not set the window frame at all.
You can add code like:

```
Window.ContentViewController.PreferredContentSize = size;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I already done all steps that you wrote in your answer. In your article I read this:
Construct an instance of the ContentPage-derived page and convert it to the appropriate native type using one of the following extension methods: CreateViewController for iOS

But problem is that my project is not IOS it for MacOS. So, main question: how I can convert ContentPage to native type for MacOS?

Comment: I already have a working application for MacOs. I have only problem described in my first topic:  opened modal window ignore size 680х425 and opened as very small square

Comment: Ok, Would you mind sharing us a baisc, minimal project to test ? You can upload it to github and attach the link here .

Comment: Ok. I have prepared for you simple Xamarin.Forms MacOS application https://gitlab.com/max9511/xamarinmacmodaltest

Please check main logic:
XamarinMacModalTest.ViewModel.MainPageViewModel where I open modal window and 

XamarinMacModalTest.macOS.Entites.Services.ModalWindowService where I open modal window in macOS.

**Current problem**: modal window that opened ignored my size (200, 200)

Comment: Hi, check the answer please